# Permission Denied while installing Airflow via Docker

Tags: linux, docker, shell, docker-compose, airflow

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

I am following the above installation guide. At the step where it says:

```
echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env
```

I think it's supposed to create a .env file, but it isn't creating anything for me. If i use the ls command .env doesn't show up.

If i try to move on to the next step:

```
docker-compose up airflow-init
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 410, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 199, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 70, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 153, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
[22636] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on an AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: `echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env` works fine for me in bash.

Comment: Have you try to add this ```echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=50000\nAIRFLOW_GID=50000" >> .env``` ? There is a discussion with that on - https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/13855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the `.env` file, it might not be visible with just the `ls` command, but probably is there. Try to execute `ls -a` to also show hidden files. Files starting with . are hidden by default.

I think your second issue is a permission issue with `docker-compose`. Try running `sudo docker-compose up airflow-init` instead, or [add your user to the docker group](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/).

Comment: after adding sudo docker-compose up airflow-init, i am not able to run docker compose up command, getting permission denied.